# Differential equation for a load bearing tapered cylinder

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I solved the problem and include its statement and solution for the benefit of other stack exchange members.

[From: *Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes, 2nd Edition* (International Series in Pure and Applied Mathematics) by George F. Simmons, p. 46 question 14]

A load $L$ is supported by a tapered circular column whose material has
density $a$. If the radius of the top of the column is $r_0$ , find the radius $r$ at a distance $x$ below the top if the areas of the horizontal cross sections are proportional to the total loads they bear.

**Solution**

Let $L(x)$ be the load borne at a cross sectional height of $x$ and let $r(x)$ be the radius at height $x$.

See that $L(0)=L$ and that $r(0)=r_0$ which implies that the proportionality constant can be written as $\frac{L}{\pi r_0^2}$. We can express the load at height $x$ by $L(x)=L+a\int_{0}^{x} \pi r(x)^2 dx$ and also the cross sectional area at $x$ by $A(x)=\pi r(x)^2$

Therefore $$L(x)=L+a\int_{0}^{x} \pi r(x)^2=\frac{L}{\pi r_0^2} \pi r(x)^2=A(x)$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ (applying the fundamental theorem of calculus) and solve the differential equation with the initial condition $r(0)=r_0$.  This yields the solution which is
\begin{equation}
\boxed{ r(x)=r_0 \exp {\frac{a \pi r_0^2 x}{2L}}.}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the same is expressed using the material constant Breaking Length $L_B=\dfrac{\sigma}{a}$ ( German: *Bruch Länge*) which is the maximum length (height) of a long column at break by gravity when hung from a point at the top. This could be interesting in DE application/STEM.

The compressive stress anywhere is the same. So,

$$\sigma= \frac{L}{A}= \frac{dL}{dA}= \frac{A\cdot a \cdot dx}{dA}$$

$$ \frac{dA}{A}= \frac{dx}{L_B}, \text{ with B.C. integrates to} $$

$$~~A =A_0 e^ {(x/L_B)}$$

which are exponential curves in some *Pagoda/Temple* architectures :

[image]

[image]